# Unknown two-pole power connector (female)

Tags: power, identification, connector, socket

I want to include a female power connector in my design.
The problem is that I do not know how to find the specific connector.

This is the male counterpart that goes into the connector.

[image]

And this is the connector that I want to incorporate:

[image]

I am not interested in exactly the same connector, as I guess there would be similar connectors available - I just don't know how to search for them.

Comment: A Chinese Christmas ornament? The pins look a little bit too centerline for that though. Diameter of the connector? Pin-pin center to center distance?

Comment: Yes, it was from that circuit! Unfortunately, i do not have a Vernier caliper ready.... I can provide this info in about 12 hours. Thanks!

Comment: How similar does the connector have to be?  Pure friction-lock connectors are difficult to come as bare parts.

Comment: Similar enough so that male cables like the ones in the first photo i posted enter and stay there....

Comment: If it's a power connector, I strongly recommend getting the *exact* match instead of a "similar" one.  My guess is it's a proprietary design, so the best option would to lop it off and replace with a design that you can source both halves of.

Comment: @vir This is a great idea! Perhaps do you know of some similar single parts?

Comment: Specific part recommendations are off-topic here but searching for "circular connectors" on any big electronics supply website (*not* Amazon, eBay, AliExpress, etc) will turn up what you need, plus the "legitimate" electronics sites will usually show you which parts are compatible.  They are definitely out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [Identiconn connector identification tool](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=propr_plastic_unlatched_circ_conn&s=L218A&fl=Z00000000000000000000000000-100-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) identified that as a [Higo L218A circular connector](https://www.higoconnector.com/products/collection/motor/w999K#title).

[image: Higo L218A]

{Higo}

Comment: Thank you very much! BTW, your tool is excellent!!! Thanks for this wonderful contribution!