# What is the name of this female connector pin?

Tags: connector, pins, power-connector

I am trying to find in the market, some female connector pins.

For reference, take a look at the pins in this SP13 connector:

[image]

[image]

The yellow pins inside are the ones I am trying to find, although I don't know how to search for this component.

I want different dimensions than this connector. For reference, the male pin that i have (for which I want to find female connector pins) is `2.3mm` in diameter and `6mm` tall.

EDIT 1: The pins that go inside are circular in shape. So I suppose the female pins I am searching for has to be circular as well. This is a picture of the male pins that go inside the connector i am searching for.

[image]

EDIT 2: I think the male connector has a locking ring. This is a picture of it. There is a movable plastic that secures it in place.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The end of that contact is a "solder cup". That's the termination end, where you solder a wire. That is not the mating end or a socket. Indeed, that contact could be either a female socket or a male pin, no way to tell from your pictures.

If you're looking for a socket that has that dropping shape on the mating face, no, there isn't one because sockets are shaped with a flat top.

If you're looking for a wire-mount socket for a 2.3 mm diameter pin, you can find it here: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/mill-max-manufacturing-corp/6433-0-19-15-42-27-10-0/11658101

If you're looking for a PCB-mount socket for a 2.3 mm diameter pin, you can find it here:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/terminals/pc-pin-receptacles-socket-connectors/324

If you're looking for a connector contact that has a solder cup at the end, then you need to tell us what connector that is.

EDIT: I see your edit. Thank you for the clarification. What you are looking for is not sockets. What you are looking for is the mate to that connector. I suggest you start a new submission, and ask: "What is the female mate to this male circular connector?" and post pictures of the male circular connector, with dimensions.

EDIT 2: Your connector looks like a [Higo L218A](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=propr_plastic_unlatched_circ_conn&s=L218A&fl=070000000000000000000000000-100-%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C%7C) (my site) but without the locking ring.

Comment: Thanks! I  just edited my question with a picture of the male connectors that enter the female ones that i want. The male pins are circular, i do not want the female pins to have any weird shape.

Comment: Oh my God, thank you so so much for this answer! You have a great site as well! Actually, i had already asked that question, but people suggested there is no such connector, and it probably is injection molded in the case. The question is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/641577/unknown-two-pole-power-connector-female  Could you please take a look at it? BTW, you have an awesome website.

Comment: You said: " I can provide this info in about 12 hours. Thanks!". I don't see it. I need the outer diameter of the plastic body of the male, please. Or, equivalently, the inner diameter of the female's outer shroud.

Comment: I said that because i did not have a vernier caliper. Since people suggested it is injection molded, i stopped trying. Unfortunately, i still do not have a Vernier Caliper. However, i measured the outer diameter with a tape measurer. It is approximately 1.2cm.... But something precise (measured with a Vernier Caliper) that i can provide is the distance between the two pins (CENTER TO CENTER). This is 6mm. Since the two pins have a thickness of 2.3mm each, then the distance between them (BOUNDARY OF PINS) is 3.7mm. I will also update the question with a pic.

Comment: I re-edited the original question with a picture of the male counterpart. I think it does have a locking ring. I added the picture for clarification.

Comment: Thank you for posting the complete information. I identified it as a Higo L218A and posted an answer in your other thread.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!! I have been researching this for quite some time and decided it is not a connector but instead injection molded. Thank you for putting me right on track! I have one more question. I open up the link on the higoconnector site, with all the connectors listed, but however, i do not see the exact female connector listed on your website, there. Which one is it exactly?